# In greenplum pxf external table get empty string while fetching element from json array of object

Tags: json, hdfs, greenplum

while accessing json data by creating external table using pxf json plugin in multiline json table example

when use following column definition

```
"coordinates.values[0]" INTEGER,
```

easily fetch 8 from below json

```
"coordinates":{
     "type":"Point",
     "values":[
           8,
           52
     ]
}
```

but if we change the json to something like this

```
"coordinates": {
     "type": "geoloc",
     "values":[
           { 
                     "latitude" : 72, 
                     "longtitue" : 80 
           }
     ]
}
```

and change the column definition like this

```
"coordinates.values[0].latitude" INTEGER,
```

fetches empty string....

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the JSON profile in PXF does not support accessing JSON objects inside arrays. However, Greenplum has very good support for JSON and you can achieve the same result by doing the following:

```sql
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE pxf_read_json (j1 json)
LOCATION ('pxf://tmp/file.json?PROFILE=hdfs:text:multi&FILE_AS_ROW=true')
FORMAT 'CSV';
```

The `pxf_read_json` table will access JSON files on the external system. Each file is read as multi-line text files, each file represents a single table row on Greenplum. You can then query the external data as follows:

```sql
SELECT values->>'latitude' as latitude, values->>'longtitue' as longitude
FROM pxf_read_json
JOIN LATERAL json_array_elements(j1->'coordinates'->'values') values
ON true;
```

With this approach, you can still take advantage of PXF's support to access external system as well as leveraging the powerful JSON support in Greenplum.

Additional information about reading a multi-Line text file into a single table row can be found [here](https://gpdb.docs.pivotal.io/latest/pxf/hdfs_fileasrow.html). And information about Greenplum support for JSON can be found [here](https://gpdb.docs.pivotal.io/latest/admin_guide/query/topics/json-data.html).